# SUMIF Conditional based sum

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'll explain whats going on with the left table first:

[image: 11]

Qty1 Normal Calculates a sum from another column, Qt2 Normal calculates a product.

The table to the right is supposed to calculate based on an entry in column B, the result in both columns M and N (even when negative). 
So basically, no matter where on Column B there will be an entry for "EUR" its suppose to sum Qty1 Normal and Qty2 Normal

I've been spending the last 2.5 hours trying to figure out, trying SUMPRODUCT, IF(SUM( and many other arguments I could try coming up and googling.

The function looks as such:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"EUR",(M:M:N:N))
```

the result should be (826000) and unfortunately I couldn't figure out what is wrong with the function I wrote.

If there is a solution within VBA that will be great, however I believe we can solve this within the simple function regions.

Thank you!!

Comment: Does `=SUMIF(B:B, "EUR", M:N)` do it for you? What about `=SUMIF(B:B, "EUR", M:M)+SUMIF(B:B, "EUR", N:N)` ?

Comment: Cant believe I didn't write here earlier haha the second one worked. 
Would you know maybe what was the reason for the first one not to calculate it correctly?

Comment: `M:M:N:N` is not a valid cell range for anything and `M:N` (two columns) cannot be used in sumif without additional consideration.